# invoking php methods directly

Tags: php, function

Why does this work:

```
$n = explode("@", "some@email.com");
echo $n[0];
```

And this **not** work?

```
explode("@", "some@email.com")[0]
```

When I try the latter, I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['
```

Answer (score 1):

It works in [later versions of PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) (>= 5.4.0):

> PHP 5.4.0 offers a wide range of new features:
>
> [...] - Function array dereferencing has been added, e.g. foo()[0]. [...]

Older versions of PHP do not support function array dereferencing, which is why you get a syntax error (PHP does not know what to do with the `[`, so it tells you it is "unexpected").

Comment: Link to some examples: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing

Comment: i'm using 5.3.6... that would explain it.  Thanks so much!  It was breaking the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) `:)`